# SoapRequest as xml string

Tags: java, android, xml, web-services, ksoap2

I have been working on an Android app and calling a WCF C# web service. I can call one of the methods correctly but having problems calling the other. Just to make sure it works, is there any way that I can use the XML request (I know that this is the XML request which the web service requires) using KSoap2? That is, can I use the XML Request as a string and set it as a parameter in order to pass that string request up to the web service, to see if I can add data to a database through the web service?

Comment: Hi @Bhavik Ambani, I see that you have an edit for my question, but I can't seem to see any changes, have you any ideas on my above question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that's interested, the following post helped me solve the problem

http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-calling-web-services/